# Why does watchEffect trigger while the watched value is not changed?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have a component which keeps a local partial copy of an Pinia storage data.

```
<template>
  <h3>Order idx {{ idx }}: sum = {{ localSum }}, store sum = {{ getOrderSum() }}</h3>
  <input type="number" v-model="localSum" />
  <button @click="updateSum">Save</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useCounterStore } from '../store/counter'
import { watchEffect, ref, defineProps, watch } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  idx: 0
})

const store = useCounterStore()

const localSum = ref(0)

function getOrderSum() {
  return store.getOrderIdxSumMap[props.idx]
}

function updateSum() {
  store.setOrderSum(props.idx, localSum.value)
}

watch(
  () => getOrderSum(),
  (newValue) => {
    console.log('i am updated')
    localSum.value = newValue
  }, {
    immediate: true,
  }
)

/*
watchEffect(() => {
  console.log('i am updated')
  localSum.value = getOrderSum()
})
*/
</script>
```

Whenever external data changes the local copy should update. Using `watchEffect` instead of `watch` causes components with modified and unsaved data to lose user input.

`watchEffect` behaviour description 1:

1. Change first order data
2. Click save
3. You'll see `i am updated` twice within console.

`watchEffect` behaviour description 2:

1. Change the first order data
2. Change the second order data
3. Click save on the first order
4. You'll see the second order changes lost

Comment out `watchEffect` and uncomment `watch`. Now everything works just fine. Is it my misconseptions or a bug worth to be reported?

[Full demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pinia-playground-forked-43fpw5?file=/src/components/order.vue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [how `watch` and `watchEffect`supposed to work](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watcheffect)

In short, `watch` and `watchEffect` both tracks the change of their dependencies. When the dependencies changed they act like follow:

- `watch` recalculates its source value and then compares the `oldValue` with `newValue`. If `oldValue` !== `newValue`, it will trigger the callback.
- `watchEffect` has no sources so it triggers the callback anyway

In your example the dependencies of both `watch` and `watchEffect` are `store.getOrderIdxSumMap` and `props.idx`. The source of `watch` is the function `() => getOrderSum()`.
 So when the `store.getOrderIdxSumMap` changed, `watchEffect` will always trigger the callback but `watch` will re-calculate the value of `() => getOrderSum()`. If it changed too, `watch` will trigger its callback

**When Vue detects a dependency is changed?**

Whenever you set a value for reactive data, Vue uses a function to decide if the value is changed as follows:

```js
export const hasChanged = (value: any, oldValue: any): boolean =>
  !Object.is(value, oldValue)
```

So setting the same value for a primitive type (number, string, boolean...) will not be considered as a value change

Comment: Does it mean `watchEffect` should execute whenever its dependencies are set? I have extended the demo above, and watchEffect is not triggered when the local ref is updated with the same value (twice clicked Reset button). Thanks for the link, your explanation makes the original source to be percepted more clearly.

Comment: @ПавелВайсберг I updated the answer to explain your concern